# Create web form and integrating with database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, forms

I want to create a online web form with many conditional logic and integrate with my own database.

On form submission, my database should save, only that data that is visible to user and submitted by user.

Which programming language and database application should I use like html, css, java script, php, jquery, Mysql, MSsql, etc.?

Comment: Whichever you'd like. What you're describing is generally described as a "web application", there are many ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Virtually any web technology stack can do this**

At a minimum, you will require PHP, HTML, and MySQL for your form. CSS is optional, but keeps the website from being ugly.

Comment: But I have too many fields/inputs with conditional form logic and some are required/compulsory fields. Which programming language should I use for same?

Comment: @Sujay You can either do this in the backend with whatever language you please (including PHP) or do it in the frontend with javascript.